# I can't see anything but the terminal when running Debian 10.3.0 in VirtualBox from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, debian, terminal

I followed the guide of this site (https://techbland.com/install-debian-9/), but for Debian 10.3.0, and when I open VirtualBox and run Debian 10.3.0 all I see is the terminal. Terminal commands work as they should (I can make directories, go in them, vim into files, etc.) but I can't get into the gui interface/desktop of debian.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Also, the mouse doesn't appear in the debian screen.

Comment: Have you checked for differences in installing between Debian 9 and 10?

Comment: No, I haven't. Everything seemed to make a lot of sense up until it didn't work (isn't that a universal truth). I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Natsu Kage pointed out, there were a few differences between installing debian 9 and 10.3. Conveniently, setting up debian 10.3 actually involved far fewer steps and was pretty straight forward.

I followed [these](https://linuxhint.com/install_debian10_virtualbox/) instructions and everything went smoothly.